# Php page don't appear when I post submit from html page

Tags: php, html, sql

I have a form action = `upload.php`  in html page but when I submit. There is  downloads box appear in the browser ask me to save or cancel or open the `upload.php`. but the php page don't appear. Please I'm waiting for solution.

Comment: what does upload.php look like?

Comment: Look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Probably your server (your _localhost_ maybe?) doesn't allow PHP...

Comment: please show your code, otherwise it's impossible to help. You might as well have asked us to find your missing sock :-)